# Creating object from scanner input

Tags: java, object

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneBook {
    
    private Address[] addresses;
    private String[] phoneNumbers;
    private Person[] people;
    
    public static void startMenu() {
        
        
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner intScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        String menu = ("Please Make A selection Below: \n1 - Add new Record"
                + " \n2 - Delete Record "
                + "\n3 - Find Record By Telephone Number "
                + "\n4 - Find Record By First Name "
                + "\n5 - Find Record By Last Name"
                + "\n6 - Update a Record"
                + "\n7 - Exit");
        
        int selection;
        String inputString;
        do {
            System.out.println(menu);
            selection = intScan.nextInt();
            Entry[] entry5 = new Entry[0];
            Entry tempEntry = null;
            switch (selection) {
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("Please enter a new record as John Michael West Doe, 574 Pole ave, St. Peter, MO, 63303, 3142752000");
            
                inputString = input.nextLine();
// creating a new obj ref variable
                tempEntry = new Entry(inputString);
                // calling the method on the obj ref variable

                tempEntry.addEntry(inputString);
                System.out.println(tempEntry.toString());
                System.out.println(menu);
                break;
                
            
            case 2:
                
                // method to remove record 
                
                break;
                
            case 3:
                
                // method 
                
                break;
                
            case 4:
                
                break;
                
            case 5:
            
                break;
                
            case 6:
                
                break;
                
            case 7:
                
                break;
            }
            
            }       while (selection != 11);

}

}
```

I'm trying to figure out why my object is not creating when I set the object reference variable equal a new Entry. I also call the .addEntry method for the tempEntry object reference variable and pass in the scanner input with no success. I just get 'null null null' printed to the console. It won't let me put in parameters though.

```
tempEntry = new Entry();
tempEntry.addEntry(inputString);
```

I'm also trying to add 1 to the Entry[] array as new records are passed in, but can't seem to find a way around that either.
I'm not sure where I'm supposed to put the:

```
tempEntry = new Entry(inputString);
```

and

```
Entry[] entry5 = new Entry[0];
```

But, I've been moving them around and running the code quite a bit. Any thoughts? Here is my add entry method in my Entry Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Entry {
    
    private Name newName;
    private Address address;
    private Phone phone;
    public String string;
    
    
    public Entry(Name newName, Address address, Phone phone) {
        this.newName = newName;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    
    public Entry(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
    
    public Entry() {
        
    }
    
    
    
    public Name getName() {
        return this.newName;
    }
    
    public Address getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }
    
    public Phone getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }
    
    public void setName(Name newName) {
        this.newName = newName;
    }
    
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    
    public void setPhone(Phone phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    **// add entry method 
    public Entry addEntry(String input) {
        String name, street, city, state, zipCode, phoneNumber;
        name = "";
        street = "";
        city = "";
        state = "";
        zipCode = "";
        phoneNumber = "";
        
        String[] arr = input.split(",");
        
        name = arr[0];
        street = arr[1].trim();
        city = arr[2].trim();
        state = arr[3].trim();
        zipCode = arr[4].trim();
        phoneNumber = arr[5].trim();
        
        Name fullName = splitName(name); 
        Address address = makeAddress(street, city, state, zipCode);
        Phone phoneNum = makePhone(phoneNumber);
        
        Entry entry1 = new Entry(fullName, address, phoneNum);
        return entry1;
    }**
    
    // split name method 
    public static Name splitName(String name) {
        String fName, mName, lName;
        fName = "";
        mName = "";
        mName = "";
        String [] names = name.split(" ");
        
        fName = names[0];
        
        for (int i = 1; i < names.length - 1; i++) {
            mName += names[i];
            if (i != names.length - 1) {
                mName += " ";
            }
        }
        
        lName = names[names.length - 1];
        
        Name name1 = new Name(fName, mName, lName);
        return name1;
    }
    
    // Address method 
    public static Address makeAddress(String street, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        Address address1 = new Address(street, city, state, zipCode);
        return address1;
    }
    
    // Phone method 
    public static Phone makePhone(String phoneNumber) {
        String area, prefix, line;
        
        area = phoneNumber.substring(0, 3);
        prefix = phoneNumber.substring(3, 6);
        line = phoneNumber.substring(6);
        
        Phone phone1 = new Phone(area, prefix, line);
        return phone1;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.newName + " " + this.address + " " + this.phone;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can remove the `addEntry()` function and take all the code that is in that function and move it to the `Entry(String string)` constructor. Except the last 2 lines. Just delete those.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp so - how would I utilize everything in there then? Would I create a new object and call that constructor? Entry entry = new Entry(inputString)?                               Also, do I need to remove anything else to paste it into that constructor? I'm just confused how it would look. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `addEntry()` function and take all the code that is in that function and move it to the `Entry(String string)` constructor. Except the last 2 lines. Just delete those.

```
public Entry(String input)
{
    String[] arr = input.split(",");
    
    if (arr.length < 6) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    newName = splitName(arr[0]);
    address = makeAddress(arr[1].trim(), arr[2].trim(), arr[3].trim(), arr[4].trim());
    phone = makePhone(arr[5].trim());
}
```

Then in the main code:

```
case 1: 
    System.out.println("Please enter a new record as John Michael West Doe, 574 Pole ave, St. Peter, MO, 63303, 3142752000");
    inputString = input.nextLine();
    tempEntry = new Entry(inputString);
    System.out.println(tempEntry.toString());
    System.out.println(menu);
    break;
```

Note that this does not add anything to the array. If you want to do that first you must declare the array correctly and set the correct index:

```
//Entry[] entry5 = new Entry[0]; <- creates a zero-length array
Entry[] entry5 = new Entry[5];   // creates array with room for 5 items
int index = 0;   // Where to add the next item
....
case 1: 
    System.out.println("Please enter a new record as John Michael West Doe, 574 Pole ave, St. Peter, MO, 63303, 3142752000");
    inputString = input.nextLine();
    entry5[index] = new Entry(inputString);
    System.out.println(entry5[index].toString());
    index += 1;
```